My Wife & I disagree Homosexuality is a sin, how do I navigate raising our kids that it is?
I will try and keep this short and to the point.
I have learned through hermeneutics and apologetics that I firmly believe Homosexuality is a sin according to what the scriptures tell us.
My wife greatly disagrees with me and thinks people can decidedly continue living in that sin and be a practicing christian involved in leadership in our church.
She and I had a discussion recently and it wasnt terrible, but it wasnt great. And I have recently realised I dont want to raise my kids teaching them this is okay and comdoned by God or the Bible like she would have them learn.
Our Church:

He sister is the worship pastor
Her sisters husband is the associate lead pastor
The lead pastor believes the same but has some rules in plac to appease the more traditional members of the church.

I am lost trying to figure out how to best navigate this situation
Nathan L.

Hi Nathan, welcome to BH.SE - unfortunately our site is not useful for this kind of question. Personally I'd highly recommend the author Preston Sprinkle, who explores these kinds of issue in a really helpful way that doesn't skirt around the Bible or lived experience - in your position I'd suggest maybe reading through one of his books together to stimulate some useful conversation. You could also reach out to him with questions or advice. His "Theology in the Raw" podcast also has some relevant episodes.

The Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange is for asking specific questions about specific texts in their original context, and so questions without specific texts are off-topic, as are questions that frame biblical passages using modern situations.
